# memsql benchmark test is so slowly when test

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, singlestore

i want to use memsql,but its so slowly when i test it use mysql benchmark.anyone can explain it?

the test cmd is

```
[root@Centos6-2 sql-bench]# perl run-all-tests  --user=root --small-test --host=127.0.0.1 --dir memsql  –log –fast
```

my server is

```
Linux Centos6-2 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
MemTotal:       32830128 kB
```

Comment: Define "slow". Is it "days" or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query compilation in MemSQL is more expensive than in MySQL as MemSQL queries are compiled with GCC into native code. But, once compiled, MemSQL will reuse compiled queries for every execution, even after restarting MemSQL.

I suggest you first run the benchmark completely for all queries to be compiled and then run the benchmark again.